# Center the Image View in in Android Studio

Tags: android, imageview

I want to center the image view in the android studio. Here is the code

Image View Code:

[image]

Output of the code:

[image]

Comment: what's your parent view ? Relative Layout, Linear Layout or Constraint Layout?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using LinearLayout with  `android:orientation="vertical"` 
 then do this

```
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="348dp"
    android:layout_height="267dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
```

full code

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="348dp"
        android:layout_height="267dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your layout is **LinearLayout**, then use this

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

or **RelativeLayout**, then use any of this for horizontal, vertical or center in parent layout

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

And for **ConstraintLayout** you can use:

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
```

Can you give image's parent layout with this question, then only we can identify the problem