# How do I center my logo in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I am trying to center my logo. Please see my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/Background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/Logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/signin"
        android:text="Sign in"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="150dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/username"
        androi/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying to center the logo image but it is not working despite me using the layout_gravity="center" tag. Please help!

Comment: Share some output pics for better understanding of the question

Comment: `android:layout_gravity` doesn't work inside a `<RelativeLayout>`. Use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center the Image View in in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67919667/center-the-image-view-in-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use center in parent.

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/Logo"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```